# rauc fails to mount .raucb files

Tags: squashfs

When I try to install a rauc package I get the following:

> root@phyboard-regor-am335x-1:/tmp# rauc install
>   phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb 
>   rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   installing
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   0% Installing
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   0% Determining slot states
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   20% Determining slot states done.
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   20% Checking bundle
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   20% Verifying signature
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   40% Verifying signature done.
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   40% Checking bundle done.
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   100% Installing failed.
>
> rauc-Message: installing
>   /tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb:
>   LastError: Failed mounting bundle: failed to run mount: Child process
>   exited with code 32
>
> Installing
>   `/tmp/phytec-qt5demo-bundle-phyboard-regor-am335x-1-20200506102456.raucb`
>   failed

When I checked, I found that `squashfs` is not recognised by linux!!! What should I do to make `squashfs` be recognised?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have squashfs support enabled in your kernel config or available as a module:

https://rauc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#kernel-configuration